# hidden dot files not being push to upstream

Tags: git, github

So I've recently been building out parts of my website. one of the thing I've done is include a .gitignore file in the root of the repository which ignores all files in the build folder. I've tested this and it works quite well, however after pushing to my the projects github repo, none of the hidden dot files end up showing in the repo. (ex: .vscode)

Here's the contents of my .gitignore file (yes, I have a git repo nested in another repo, it hasn't caused any problems yet ;) ):

```
build/*
!build/.git
!build/.gitkeep
```

what is going on here? I have a pretty straight-forwards setup but it seems nobody really has the exact problem as I do. anybody ever run into this?

also I should say, I've had one mention that the dot files might still be being pushed to the upstream repo, just they arn't checked out. if so how do i reveal them when cloning?

Comment: Have you considered using a git submodules to avoid this problem altogether? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: `git` will completely skip a nested repo. That is : even before looking at what should be `.gitignored` and what should not be, if it detects that a subdirectory is a git repo, it ignores it. If you want to include a repo within your repo, the most standard way is to use submodules.

Comment: Can you described what the repository inside the `build/` folder contains, and how you intend to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

As @legec put it, Submodules are usually the way to go. But be careful there are a lot of nuance when working around submodules.

to get more info before knowing if using submodules is wise for your use case, checkout https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule